# Reading a file throws an exception

Tags: c++, file, exception, ifstream

Does anyone have any idea what am i doing wrong

```
inputFileName = argv[1];
outputFileName = argv[2];

std::ifstream readFile;
readFile.exceptions (std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
//set the flags for stream bits that indicate failure if ON
std::ofstream writeFile;
writeFile.exceptions (std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

try{
    readFile.open(inputFileName);
    writeFile.open(outputFileName);

    //do some stuff

    readFile.close();
    writeFile.close();
}
catch(std::ifstream::failure &readErr) {
    std::cerr << "\n\nException occured when reading a file\n"
         << readErr.what()
         << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
catch(std::ofstream::failure &writeErr) {
    std::cerr << "\n\nException occured when writing to a file\n"
         << writeErr.what()
         << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

When compiling I get

```
warning: exception of type 'std::ios_base::failure' will be caught [enabled by default]
     catch(std::ofstream::failure &writeErr) {
     ^
warning:    by earlier handler for 'std::ios_base::failure' [enabled by default]
     catch(std::ifstream::failure &readErr) {
     ^
```

And when I run the code, the `Exception occured when reading a file` and the readErr.what() `basic_ios::clear` print.

I looked up a lot of examples and i can't see where i went wrong. Also, I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 if it helps.

Comment: You appear to have included all the code *except* the code you say is causing an error.

Comment: So you are saying that how i read(`getline`) is what throws the exception

Comment: Please make sure your code is complete and can be compiled immediately, instead of us having to add the `#include`s and `main()`. Ideone.com is a great place to prepare a complete testcase.

Comment: The compiler warnings just reflect that `std::ofstream::failure` and `std::ifstream::failure` are both the same thing - inherited from `std::ios_base`.  You can't catch them separately, which also means that your "Exception occured when reading a file" is *potentially* misleading - it may equally have been the `ofstream` that threw.  You could put lines of trace between the `.open` calls and down through the function so you know how far it got before throwing, or use a debugger.

Comment: I compiled your snippet at http://ideone.com/h0QMQ4 and the program threw a different exception.

Comment: *"So you are saying that how i read(getline) is what throws the exception"* - You are getting an exception because you told the system to throw an exception on failure. So I assumed your question was about why the read failed. All the exception code doesn't seem relevant to that. But your input/output code might be.

Comment: @FabioA.Correa sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @TonyD How can I separate the exceptions then right way

Comment: For example, if you were trying to read in an integer and the file contained some text, the read would fail (and an exception generated). How are we to know if you are calling `std::getline()` or using `>>` while trying to read an `int` if we can't see that code?

Comment: `basic_ios::clear` could mean that your file is empty or not there. Check http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1243086

Comment: @Galik An exception is thrown before i'm actually trying to read, so right after `readFile.open(inputFileName)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I printed `argv[0]` and saw that IDE actually runs the program in a different directory. Sorry for my negligence

Answer (score 1):

Does the *inputFileName* exists? Just write:

```
  catch ( std::exception const& e ) {
     std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
   }
```

Comment: `Exception: basic_ios::clear` is printed. Yes, it exists

Comment: Just test whether readFile is a valid stream by checking 'if ( readFile ) { // valid } else { invalid }'

Comment: Developers have both options: exceptions and `if()` tests. Exceptions are slower to create and handle but are more descriptive of what went wrong. -- Except in this case in which we don't know what went wrong.

Comment: After executing `readFile.open(inputFileName)` nothing else prints... So probably something is wrong with the file, but what?

Comment: Please print the filename ´inputFileName´ and check whether ´readFile.good()´ is ´true´.

Comment: the `inputFileName` is legit. I tried `if(readFile.good()) std::cout << "true";`  after `readFile.open(inputFileName)` but exception was thrown

Comment: I made a new file and inserted it's name in `readFile.open("newFile.txt");` but same thing :/

Comment: @user2202368: are you certain those files are the ***current working directory*** the program is running in?  If you're running the program from some kind of IDE it might change that directory to some configured value.  It's a good idea to hardcode an absolute filesystem location first, and/or print out your current working directory from the code.